# Angular scope function executed twice when it should only run once?

Tags: angularjs

**[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gSesl1tBlrR4gLMbjYDW?p=preview)**

Quick question: in the following code I only call the function `isSpecificPage()` once, why it console.log twice?

```
<div ng-hide="isSpecificPage()">
  <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular puts a watch on your `ng-hide` function so that every digest cycle it can see if the results changed (and thus if it needs to change from hiding to showing your element or vice-versa).

When watched functions are evaluated (during `$digest`) if any of them have changed from the previous `$digest` then Angular knows that change might ripple through to other watched functions (perhaps the changed variable is used in another watched function).  So every watch is re-evaluated (also called dirty processing) until none of the watches results in a change.  Thus typically you'll see 2 calls to watched functions per digest and sometimes more (up to 10- at 10 loops through it gives up and reports an error saying it can't stabilize).

Here's more on `watch` and `digest`:

> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope
>
> http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Comment: thanks, and I wonder if there's a way to reduce the times, that is am I able to only run the function once?

Comment: Not within an `ng-hide`.  Angular needs this mechanism so it can change the visibility of your element whenever the results of your conditional change.  What's your motivation for fewer calls?

Answer (score -1):

`ng-hide` is one of the directives that uses `$watch` internally. Since `$watch` uses digest cycle(which runs atleast 2 times to check if the value has changed or not), so your function `isSpecificPage` has run twice.

For a list of directives that use `$watch` internally,  refer this stackoverflow answer [directives that add watch internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216294/what-gets-added-to-scope-watchers-by-default-in-angular-and-what-triggers-d).