# Why is ng-style function applied twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an angular app like:

```
angular.module('ngStyleApp', [])

.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.list = [1,2,3];
   $scope.getStyles = function(index) {
       console.log('getting styles for index ' + index);
       return {
           color: 'red'
       };
   };
});
```

with the corresponding markup:

```
<div ng-app="ngStyleApp">
    <ul ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="value in list" ng-style="getStyles($index)">
            {{value}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The visible output is three red list items, as expected. But the statement is logged to the console a total of 6 times, implying that the view is rendered twice:

```
getting styles for index 0
getting styles for index 1
getting styles for index 2
getting styles for index 0
getting styles for index 1
getting styles for index 2
```

**Why?**

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/3rje314h/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Angular `$digest` cycle evaluates the ngStyle attribute at least twice - once to get the value and once to check if it has changed. It actually keeps iterating until the value settles so could potentially check the value many times.

Here's a picture to illustrate this:

[image]

Here is a good blog post illustrating this:
[angular digest blog](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/)

Actually, try this quote from StackOverflow that says it very well:

> When watched functions are evaluated (during $digest) if any of them have changed from the previous $digest then Angular knows that change might ripple through to other watched functions (perhaps the changed variable is used in another watched function). So every watch is re-evaluated (also called dirty processing) until none of the watches results in a change. Thus typically you'll see 2 calls to watched functions per digest and sometimes more (up to 10- at 10 loops through it gives up and reports an error saying it can't stabilize).

(Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993294/angular-scope-function-executed-twice-when-it-should-only-run-once))

Comment: Then, why is that ng-init is only called once?

Comment: ng-init does just that - it is used to set up a value once to initialize the directive

Comment: It is because ng-init does not need to reevaluate, it does not register any watches..No dirty checks basically needed.

Comment: @PSL the reason why ngInit doesn't get executed again is because ngInit doesn't have a watch, while ngStyle does. What I mean with this is that it's the watch of the directive what makes the function to be called twice, not the cycle itself (the cycle makes it possible, of course, but it's not the real reason).

Comment: @Josep I think you make a good point - the watch is definitely why the function gets called twice.

Comment: @Josep yes that is what i mentioned in my comment (unless my wording was wrong :)), watches are registered for dirty checks during the digest cycle and to decide whether there is an update or not, in case of ng-init it does update during the first digest cycle, it is only for initialization  there is no need to reevaluate it

Comment: @PSL I wasn't trying to rectify what you said, I just wanted to make clear what my point was with my first comment ;) Thanks!

Comment: @CaspNZ thanks; this makes sense. In my real-life case, the function providing styles is using a non-trivial algorithm to determine the absolute positioning of its respective element, and I'm seeing it called up to seven times per digest loop (I'm guessing due to my nested controller/directive setup). This understanding makes me want to pre-compute those values and store them in the controller, so the ng-style function just reads them.

Comment: @Josep oh no i dint mean that, sometimes my English isn't that good :(, so was just making sure by explaining again what i meant.. lol. Anytime happy to get my understanding rectfied though.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code of the `ngStyle` directive:

```
var ngStyleDirective = ngDirective(function(scope, element, attr) {
  scope.$watch(attr.ngStyle, function ngStyleWatchAction(newStyles, oldStyles) {
    if (oldStyles && (newStyles !== oldStyles)) {
      forEach(oldStyles, function(val, style) { element.css(style, '');});
    }
    if (newStyles) element.css(newStyles);
  }, true);
});
```

Notice that there is a `scope.$watch` for `attr.ngStyle`, that watch is what is making it trigger twice.

For instance, if you try to do the same thing using `ngInit`, you will notice that the function only gets called once. Now, lets have a look at the code of the `ngInit` directive, it looks like this:

```
var ngInitDirective = ngDirective({
  priority: 450,
  compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Notice that there is no `watch` in this directive.