# Function launched too many times on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a **serious performance problem**.

I want to show details in a list, but the function is called too many times.

You can [try demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23435/)

Here is HTML code :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
<p>Watch your console, then click on a letter. Why "myterious" function is launched so many time ???</p>
<button ng-click="ctrl.setValue('B')">Display B</button>
<button ng-click="ctrl.setValue('C')">Display C</button>
<button ng-click="ctrl.setValue('D')">Display D</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.vitals track by $index">
    <p ng-click="ctrl.toggleDetail($index)" ng-bind="item.name"></p>
    <div ng-show="ctrl.myterious(item.name, ctrl.value)">This should only be display under {{item.name}}</div>
    <div ng-show="ctrl.display[$index]">...</div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is my JavaScript code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {
    var self = this;

    self.vitals = [
            {name:'A'},
            {name:'B'},
            {name:'C'},
            {name:'D'},
            {name:'E'},
            {name:'F'},
            {name:'G'},
            {name:'H'},
            {name:'I'},
            {name:'J'},
            {name:'K'}
    ];

    self.display = [];
    self.toggleDetail = function(id) {
            console.log("Toggle launched");
        self.display[id] = !self.display[id];
    };

    self.value = 'B';
    self.setValue = function (val) {
        self.value = val;
    }

    self.myterious = function (a, b) {
        console.log(a + ' ' + new Date().getTime());
        if (a === b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I'd like to know **where** is the problem and how to **fix** it, because it is a simplification of my original code.

Comment: Also note that if you make the variable equal to a function, it will behave differently than a value. Ex: `self.example = function() { return 'ex'; }` behaves differently than `self.example = ex;`

Comment: Indeed, it was the root of my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for all of the function calls is the ng-show binding. Every time the DOM is updated, it runs the mysterious function to determine whether or not to display the item. In order to avoid all of these function calls, your ng-show bindings should be based on something static. See modified example below:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apw4kvb0/1/)

```
self.vitals = [
      {name:'A', mysterious: false},
      {name:'B', mysterious: true},
      {name:'C', mysterious: false},
      {name:'D', mysterious: false},
      {name:'E', mysterious: false},
      {name:'F', mysterious: false},
      {name:'G', mysterious: false},
      {name:'H', mysterious: false},
      {name:'I', mysterious: false},
      {name:'J', mysterious: false},
      {name:'K', mysterious: false}
    ];

self.setValue = function (val) {
        self.vitals.forEach(function(obj) {
         obj.mysterious = obj.name == val
         })
        self.value = val;
    }

<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.vitals track by $index">
    <p ng-click="ctrl.toggleDetail($index)" ng-bind="item.name"></p>
    <div ng-show="item.mysterious">
        This should only be display under {{item.name}}  
   </div> </div>
```

Without knowing the specifics of your goal, there is typically nothing wrong with a lightweight function executing frequently to determine dom visibility. The only time I have seen this become a problem is when this gets out of control. If you have a legitimate business reason for calculating a dom's visibility dynamically, use it as sparingly as possible. Otherwise, do your  best to design your visibility logic based on static (non-function) bindings.

Comment: Very nice answer, it is the extension of Christopher Schröder and Shitsu but with concrete code, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

This is because AngularJS re-execute the `ng-repeat` loop any time the data (here `ctrl.vitals`) or any flag, variable, etc. used inside the loop might have changed.

Here, your `mysterious` is inside an `ng-if`, hence it needs to be executed for each iteration.

There are also more subtleties, which are better explained in this article: [Banging Your Head Against an AngularJS Issue? Try This](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! So what I should I do to avoid that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Basically, I have a list, and when I press on a row, I want to display more details. Problem is function is launched too many times, and it kills my perfs..

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise your function gets called **twice** the times it would be expected to. As ng-repeat is a directive and directives can be executed twice or more, this is perfectly normal.

This has been answered multiple times, see [Why is ng-style function applied twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926120/why-is-ng-style-function-applied-twice) for a nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the topic, so what should I do to avoid that ? What are the best practices for this case ?

Comment: (Thanks for providing updating the plunker by the way, this really helps.) This means you should use ng-repeat only for displaying your data (avoid doing expensive computations within the repeat loop). See the updated plunker for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7v642twm/.

Comment: (No problem, thanks to you for the reply :) ) OK... So I have to avoid to use functions inside ng-repeat, and use some flags instead... Seems so simple and logical, but I haven't do that... Thank you !