# What gets added to $scope.$$watchers by default in Angular? And what triggers $digests?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I'm reading [Build Your Own AngularJS](http://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular) and have a decent understanding of how `$scopes`, `$watch` and `$digest` work. I understand how it works when you add your own `$watches` and and call your own `$digests`. However, I'm confused about what exactly is happening *by default*.

1. What gets added to `$scope.$$watchers` by default? Everything you put on `$scope`? Everything you assign an `ng-model` to? Both? Something else?
2. And when exactly do `$digests` get triggered by default? Input field changes? Input fields with `ng-models`? Other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of the common directives that use `$watch` / `$watchCollection` / `$watchGroup` internally:

1. ng-model
2. ng-bind / {{ }}
3. ng-show & ng-hide
4. ng-class
5. ng-repeat
6. ng-if
7. ng-switch
8. ng-include

Note that the only one that sets up a two-way binding is `ng-model` (scope -> view & view -> scope).

The others set up a one-way binding (scope -> view).

Simply exposing something on for example a controller´s `$scope` will **not** add a watcher.

For example, the following will not result in a watcher being added:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Controller', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.value = 1;
});
```

Together with:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
</body>
```

But if you replace the HTML with the following one watcher will be added:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
  <div>{{value}}</div>
</body>
```

---

Some common scenarios when the digest cycle is triggered:

1. When `ng-click` is evaluated
2. When `ng-model` changes (for example when typing in an input)
3. By the `$http` service
4. In `$timeout` and `$interval`

---

Note that there is one big difference between `$apply` and `$digest`:

Calling `scope.$digest()` will execute the watchers only on that scope and its children.

Calling `scope.$apply()` will trigger `$digest` on the `$rootScope`, which means all the scopes will be traversed and all watchers executed.

`$apply` also accepts an expression as an argument. This expression will be evaluated inside a try-catch statement and any exception will be passed on to the `$exceptionHandler` service.

`$digest` does not accept any arguments.

Usually you only call `$digest` instead of `$apply` when you are chasing micro optimizations and really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that any two-way bindings get a `$watch` in their scope, however, if it is added by angular internals, you don't get that hook, because, for example, `ngModelController` has the callback, so you can't use that callback, I think what is on scope does not get a watch unless it is bound to the view.

`$digest` is not used on model binding from what I found in the source code - but I found plenty of uses of `$apply`. In fact I found very few uses of `$digest` in the angular code at all. I didn't look in every file, but I did find it used in the expression parser [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js). Which I find interesting, but to answer your question, `$digest` in not called often, and `$apply` is called on only a few occasions with model binding, most notably on `$commitViewValue()` in the `ngModelController`. It also calls apply when an input is "touched"(`ng-touched`). I also found that `$evalAsync` calls `$digest` as well.

What I found for certain on apply/digest:

```
//apply method in rootScope
$apply: function(expr) {
    try {
      beginPhase('$apply');
      return this.$eval(expr);
    } catch (e) {
      $exceptionHandler(e);
    } finally {
      clearPhase();
      try {
        $rootScope.$digest();
      } catch (e) {
        $exceptionHandler(e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, apply is really just a safe wrap around `$digest`, so one might argue to use $apply over digest. According to the source $digest does some crazy while-loop `$scope` traversal.

**TLDR;**

The notes from the angular team on digest:

> Processes all of the {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch watchers} of
>   the current scope and
>   its children. Because a {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch watcher}'s listener can change
>   the model, the `$digest()` keeps calling the {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch watchers}
>   until no more listeners are firing. This means that it is possible to get into an infinite
>   loop. This function will throw `'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.'` if the number of
>   iterations exceeds 10.
>
> Usually, you don't call `$digest()` directly in
>   {@link ng.directive:ngController controllers} or in
>   {@link ng.$compileProvider#directive directives}.
>   Instead, you should call {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply $apply()} (typically from within
>   a {@link ng.$compileProvider#directive directive}), which will force a `$digest()`.
>
> If you want to be notified whenever `$digest()` is called,
>   you can register a `watchExpression` function with
>   {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch $watch()} with no `listener`.