# $watch fires on focus lost

Tags: angularjs, nicescroll

I have a `textarea` tag with [jquery.nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) pluggin and ng-model attached to it.

```
<textarea id="paper" ng-model="paper"></textarea>
```

In my code I apply a `$watch` on this ng-model variable.

```
$scope.$watch("paper", onTextChange);
```

Everything is good except that *onTextChange* is fired not only when I type something, but when I click away from textareaб and also when I switch to another tab.

How can I prevent it so that *onTextChange* is fired only when the text is changed, meaning when I type in something or delete chars?

**Demo with instructions:** [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVjpBWiyhPj1t7O4IyUq?p=preview)

Comment: you use watch to listen to changes to paper, not to event onTextChange.So when paper change, it executes your function.

Comment: nope, by that statement I am telling angular to watch for **paper** variable changes (in $scope) and fire up my **onTextChanged()** function if that variable is changed. And because it is bound to my textarea via ng-model, this event should be fired when I type something in textarea. Which IS fired, but not only when I type in something, but also when I only scroll down/up and click away. Which is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a fix:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kycmUrthYU38Ukdz0jJG?p=preview

```
setTimeout( 
function() {
    $scope.$watch("paper", function(newtext, oldtext) {
      if (newtext !== oldtext) {
        onTextChange();
      }
    });
  }, 100)
```

So the issue is that watch fires the function whenever angularjs tells the app to digest. What you did was tell it to call the 'change' function EVERY time, when you should have passed in a checker function to check the change happened. It's about 'watching', not about **'watching for changes'** - the function argument is supposed to see if you need to do something.

Extra note:

AngularJS sets up watchers for all kinds of things on various elements - here's a bit more info. I believe the blur corresponds to ng-touched which triggers the digest [What gets added to $scope.$$watchers by default in Angular? And what triggers $digests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216294/what-gets-added-to-scope-watchers-by-default-in-angular-and-what-triggers-d)

Comment: I think if you remove setTimeout, onTextChange method will get called on load event as theextbox is initially empty and there may be little delay in text populated in textbox..

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to use `setTimeout`. Instead, you could use `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"` and write a method to get/set the value ([Modified get/set Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkqmj0n9n8HFDWclOB4W?p=preview)) and handle the text change condition within this method.

Comment: I will look at your plunk, it's something new to me. Thank you