# Function inside AngularJS controller is called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an anonymous function tied to the `$scope` in AngularJS. Problem is that the function is invoked 2 times and hence the *"Hello!"* is alerted twice.

I have no explicit `watch` defined on the function.

I know that this is somehow related to Angular **digest cycle**, but I am not able to understand how.

```js
angular.module("root", [])
  .controller("index", function($scope) {
    $scope.myObj = {};
    $scope.myObj.text = function() {
      alert("Hello!");
      return "<b>Hello!</b>";
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <body ng-app="root">
    <p ng-controller="index">
      <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="myObj.text()"></span>
    </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993294/angular-scope-function-executed-twice-when-it-should-only-run-once. Angular has to watch ng-bind-html-unsafe to update the DOM, and watched expressions are evaluated at least twice: the first time to update the value, the second time to ensure the value stays the same (checks possible side effects of the first first call) .

Answer (score 0):

One quick and maybe (dirty) way to fix this is:

```js
angular.module("root", [])
  .controller("index", function($scope) {
    var initializeController = false;
    $scope.myObj = {};
    $scope.myObj.text = function() {
      if (!initializeController) {
        initializeController = true;
        alert("Hello!");
        return "<b>Hello!</b>";
      }
    }
  });
```